# How to go to the other round of two loops at the same time?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

How to go to the other round of two loops at the same time?

Code:

```
parameters = {'CT', 'Imp', 'F1', 'F2'};    
Time = {'T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6'};
for i_parameters = 1: numel(parameters)
    my_parameters = parameters{i_parameters};
    for i_Time = 1 : numel (Time) 
        my_time = Time{i_Time};
        for j = 1 : 7
            Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time) = [Diff.(my_parameters)(:,j); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,j+7); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,j+14); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,j+21); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,j+28)];
            DiffMean.(my_parameters).(my_time) = mean(Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time));
            Diffstd.(my_parameters).(my_time) = std(Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time));
        end 
    end
end
```

I would like to leave the loops `i` and`i_Time` at each turn and at the same time that I would like to apply:
`i_Time = T0` then `j = 1 / i_Time = T1` then `j = 2 / i_Time = T2` then `j = 3 / i_Time = T3` then `j = 4 / i_Time = T4` then `j = 5 / i_Time = T5` then `j = 6 / i_Time = T6` then `j = 7`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's very simple. I bothered to create a variable `j` while it is useless.

Here is the code that works:

```
parameters = {'CT', 'Imp', 'F1', 'F2'};
Time = {'T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6'};
for i_parameters = 1: numel(parameters)
    my_parameters = parameters{i_parameters};
    for i_Time = 1 : numel (Time)
        my_time = Time{i_Time};     
        Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time) = [Diff.(my_parameters)(:,i_Time); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,i_Time+7);
            Diff.(my_parameters)(:,i_Time+14); Diff.(my_parameters)(:,i_Time+21);
            Diff.(my_parameters)(:,i_Time+28)];
        DiffMean.(my_parameters).(my_time) = mean(Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time));
        Diffstd.(my_parameters).(my_time) = std(Difference.(my_parameters).(my_time));
    end
end
```